# How to validate that cython debugger is active in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed the cython debugger in PyCharm (2018.1) via a little pop-up dialogue box link, it seemed to install. I restarted PyCharm to be sure.

A particular debugging session is obscenely slow, slower than I expect (30 minutes to reach a point that normally takes 30 seconds outside the debugger).

In the first lines of console output I don't note any reference to cython, and **I'm wondering if cython is installed and running properly or not.** I don't know how to validate this.

```
/home/davidparks21/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf17_cpu/bin/python /home/davidparks21/opt/pycharm-2017.3.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 34818 --file /home/davidparks21/myprojects/eg_tensorflow/src/nntf/trainer.py
pydev debugger: process 24630 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.4203.547)
```

How can I validate that the cython debugging is running? Should I expect something in my console output to validate this.

I am using conda environments if that makes any difference.

Following the pycharm [documentation here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cython-speedups.html), it seems like I've done things right, but I can't validate so.

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can add a bounty on the question if you want to bump it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to disable cython debugger extensions and compare timings.

According to [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugger-python.html): if someone doesn't want to use Cython extensions, the environment variable `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` should be passed.

I tried few debug runs with `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO` and `PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=YES`. I supplied different values in run configurations. In my case I've got about 20% time difference. Seems like cython works for me.

PS: Anyway I still have the popup that recommends me to install cython extension.